# Installing Ubuntu on a new Dell Inspiron 14-5000 laptop with RAID-0

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, dell, raid

The laptop is https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-laptops/new-inspiron-14-5000-laptop/spd/inspiron-14-5493-laptop

The problem is very similar to the one reported here: [Install Ubuntu on Dell Inspiron 14 7490](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204648/install-ubuntu-on-dell-inspiron-14-7490)

The laptop has an 512 GB SSD but it is split into 2 RAID-0 partitions. I can start the Ubuntu installation program on a USB but it does not see any HD.

At the moment I cannot even boot the laptop with a USB drive. I need to start Windows 10, go to advanced boot options and restart using USB there.
Thus I'm afraid that if I mess up somewhere, the laptop won't boot at all.

Answer (score 0):

To install, you need to change your BIOS from RAID to AHCI and turn off secure boot.  You'll need to boot Windows into safe mode after making these changes so that it will continue to work, if you want it to.  If you go into the BIOS on boot and you have your flash drive plugged in, you can choose then to boot from the flash drive to install Ubuntu.

Comment: I would have provided this as a comment but I do not have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: @0xF2 It looks like an answer to me.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that next week. This laptop has a strange configuration. Secure boot is turned off. On boot, it says "press F12 to select boot device" but hitting F12 does nothing.