# Does Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04 work on Dell Latitude 7310

Tags: 18.04, 20.04

Earlier, I purchased Dell Inspiron 7490. But I (and our team) could not install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on it due to unsupported Intel RST drives. Further, when I switched to AHCI mode on startup, the disk is not visible. I searched a lot for this on the Net. Most of the sites said that it is not possible including this link: [Install Ubuntu on Dell Inspiron 14 7490](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204648/install-ubuntu-on-dell-inspiron-14-7490)

So, I gave up on the installing Ubuntu on Inspiron 7490 and returned the laptop. I lost a lot of time in this process.

Now, I am planning to buy Dell Latitude 7310.  I want to have ensure that I will be able to install Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04  LTS. Has anyone in this forum has successfully been aboe to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS  or Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on Dell Latitude 7310?  If yes, could you share the BIOS firmware version (sudo dmidecode -t BIOS)?

The dell website says that they support they support Ubuntu® 18.04.3 LTS on Dell Latitude 7310:
https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-in/drivers/supportedos/latitude-13-7310-2-in-1-laptop

Thanks in advance.

Sathya

Comment: Did you update the bios on the 7490?  It looks like there was an update recently, and they do indicate Ubuntu 16 is supported.  Odd that it doesn't list 18.

Comment: @rtaft, we installed the latest bios on  Dell Inspiron 7490. Yet, we could not install the Ubuntu 20.04 on it. So, I gave up and returned it. Now, I am hoping that Ubuntu will run well on Dell Latitude 7310.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: @Karel, I have not yet purchased the Dell Latitude 7310. I hope to purchase based on the answers provided. Earlier, I had a bad experience with Inspiron 7490. So, I wanted to be sure before I can purchase it. Latitute 7310 is not a cheap laptop. Thanks!

Comment: If Dell website says that the Dell Latitude 7310 supports Ubuntu then it supports Ubuntu, so you have no question for Ask Ubuntu to answer here. Hardware is the key. Although hardware shopping recommendations are off topic at Ask Ubuntu, if I were you I would scour the internet for customer reviews of product quality of this laptop before buying it.

Comment: Thanks Karel for responding back. That is the problem with Dell. Dell mentions that it Inspiron 7490 supports Ubuntu 16.04. But it is not free version downloaded from ubuntu.com. It is some variant of Ubuntu. Further, I was unable to get  Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04 installed on Dell Inspiron 7490. I am hoping that I don't run into similar difficulties with Dell Latitude 7310. So, I am asking this question here. My objective here is not to ask about the quality of the product here.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting back to this in a delayed manner. I was successfully able to install Ubuntu 20.04 on Dell Latitude 7310. So far, everything has worked well.

I had some difficulties with HP printer setup. But after some digging around, I found the answer to that as well.

Thanks!