# Would replace SSD disable Intel RST/fake RAID?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd, rst, fakeraid

I would like to install ubuntu on my Dell Inspiron 7490. However, as mentioned on this thread
[Install Ubuntu on Dell Inspiron 14 7490](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204648/install-ubuntu-on-dell-inspiron-14-7490) the BIOS doesn't allow disabling the FAKE RAID.

I'm willing to replace the SSD if that solves the problem. So the question is, if I replace the SSD would that help?

Thanks

Comment: are you sure the BIOS doesn't have a "SATA MODE" option to change to AHCI straight rather than 'fake raid' or Intel RST options?  All dell laptops have had thed option to disable RST or AHCI+RAID and go right to plain AHCI mode in the past 5 years at least.

Comment: @ThomasWard yes I'm pretty sure. I have tried to update the BIOS as well, I'm using a very recent version released 1.5.3. It's exactly the same screenshot as the person on the other question have. It either disables the SATA controller which means, no SSD at all, or that RAID on.