# How to install ubuntu 20.04 on Intel RST and not AHCI

Tags: 20.04, usb-installation, ahci, rst

I have Dell Inspiron 7501 with 512 GB NVME PCIe M.2 SSD and I have been trying to dualboot ubuntu 20.04. But while installing, it says that 'This computer works on RST. Turn off RST to install ubuntu'[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bAI5.jpg). So, is there any method to install ubuntu on RST and not on AHCI as I have read that AHCI configuration reduces the lifespan of SSDs. Or suggest any other distro if this problem is ubuntu specific.

Comment: Where did you see that AHCI has issues? Back in early days, you had to manually enable trim to improve things. Windows AHCI instructions - some have found safeboot method better
https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Dell-M-2-FAQ-regarding-AHCI-vs-RAID-ON-Storage-Drivers-M-2-Lanes/td-p/5072571 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems & 
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347

Comment: I have 2 SSDs setup on AHCI and I have been using them for years without any problems.

Comment: Have read some comments that it can be done only if it is single boot of Ubuntu.  If Windows is on computer and you want to keep Windows, it needs to be AHCI.  Read up on how to change Windows to AHCI before doing.

Comment: @oldfred  update: I tried lubuntu and ubuntu 18.04. In both of them, the installer is unable to see the internal hard disk. The partition section is totally empty. Can anyone explain in detail what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Windows can use fast boot and/or dynamic partitions, both can mess up Ubuntu seeing them.  Fast boot is safe to turn off in Windows.  Dynamic is not safe to change to basic.

Comment: @crip659 i have made logical partitions and fast/secure boot is turned off but still facing the problem

Comment: Go into Windows and use it's disk manager to see what type of partition Windows is using.  Do Not change.  Ubuntu likes Windows to use basic partitions to see them.  Do not change or will mess up Windows.

Comment: Dell also typically needs UEFI update & SSD firmware update. Do you have most current versions of firmware? Most not seeing drive are settings not AHCI, Windows fast start up  stilll on, and a few other minor issues not as often seen like dynamic partitions. Issues often common across similar models by brand. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204648/install-ubuntu-on-dell-inspiron-14-7490 & https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln151664/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en