# Ubuntu partition does not turn on, but Windows partition works fine

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows

My computer originally came with Windows 10. I decided to partition the disk in Ubuntu 20 and Windows 10. Both operative systems worked fine for 2-3 months, but one day Ubuntu just did not work anymore. When I turn on the computer and select to start with Ubuntu, the screen shows its brand, and then it stays black and nothing happens, I cannot come back and the computer does not obey any order, therefore I must unplug the computer.
When I select to use Windows it works fine, it starts fast and there is not problem.

Do you know how to fix and recover Ubuntu? I have a couple of files in that partition and I would like to recover those.

Edit: The computer is Del (OptiPlex 7070). The processor is Intel (R) Core (TM) i7-9700 CPU@3.00GHz 3.00GHz. It has an operative system of 64-bits.
Windows version is 1909.
The video card is Interl (R) UHD Graphics 630.
I am not sure if the system did updates, but I took these pictures of the settings of UEFI.

[General system information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcqjU.png)

[Boot sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jC8n.png)

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20. What is the OS version?

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Did Windows do updates and did it also update UEFI? Update of UEFI may change some settings to defaults, so double check those. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I added the information that you asked me to the question @oldfred

Comment: It is Ubuntu 20.04 @Pilot6

Comment: Are you able to boot recovery mode? Second line in grub menu? Issues often common by brand, then by AMD or Intel within brand as similar UEFI used, and just updated to match hardware options.Dell 7490 Intel RST issues
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204648/install-ubuntu-on-dell-inspiron-14-7490

Comment: I did what @oldfred and Amint suggested and it worked! There were 5 recovery modes, the first one did not work but the second did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has happened to me with some distros, mostly Manjaro (I use Ubuntu too, [Regolith](https://regolith-linux.org) to be exact as a dual boot system.) The way I get through it is by trying to boot a different kernel, or the fallback initrd, which in this case, is the recovery boot. You can do this by going to *Advanced options for Ubuntu*, and clicking Ubuntu, with Linux (kernel ver here) or Ubuntu, with Linux (kernel ver here) (recovery initram).

Answer (score 0):

Use Shift + F2 after choosing ubuntu from bootloader to show boot messages.
Alternative would be to boot from usb drive (as a live system) and backup your data before you try to repair your ubuntu from usb drive.

Comment: Hello Roger! I used Alt+F2 but nothing happened. I am going to boot from USB but honestly, I am not sure how to do it, is it similar to the process that one does when installing Ubuntu? https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you want, but I've had dual boot configs for Windows and Ubuntu over at least a dozen years. They co-existed more or less peacefully until UEFI came along. The maintenance work on either OS when UEFI is in the picture has added hours of troubleshooting tasks especially after installing patches to fix the UEFI.

It's just not worth the stress or risk of losing files over this. Get a separate machine for Ubuntu and avoid the trap.