# Should I set up Ubuntu as dual-boot and what partition size should I choose?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10

I've got a new Windows 10 laptop which I want to use Linux on. Although I haven't finally chosen a distribution I'm interested in Ubuntu and Ubuntu-based ones. Despite hours of internet search regarding this topic I still have some questions left.

The new laptop:

- Dell Inspiron 14 Model 7400
- Windows 10 included, but not set up yet
- i7 processor
- Nvidia GeForce MX350
- 16GB RAM
- 1TB SSD

Here's what I'd like to know:

If I set up a dual-boot:

1. Is it correct that Windows and Linux are able to access each other's files if both partitions are NTFS?
2. Is it correct that the Linux partition's size limits the space available for Linux applications?
3. How much space does Windows need at minimum? What partition sizes would you recommend on my 1TB SSD? (I tend to give Linux more space and keep Windows only as a fallback.)

If I install only Linux:

4. Do you think the laptop's built-in fingerprint sensor is supported by Linux? (I mean: How likely is that? I didn't find anything specific online.)
5. *(If I don't like Linux: Will I be able to re-install Windows 10 using the product key from the pre-installed Windows 10? **This Microsoft Community thread suggests so**: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/can-i-use-the-product-key-of-pre-installed-windows/f1d82f86-200d-47e5-8f8e-ba32e549b0b2)*

Comment: Way too many questions, some of them very subjective, and others are easily answered by searching. Also, Linux is just a kernel, so if you install "only Linux", it will not do much.

Comment: @mikewhatever When the OP says "Linux", I'm pretty sure they mean a Linux distro, and guessing by the questions and that they are on Ask Ubuntu, probably Ubuntu.

Comment: Replace "Linux" with "Ubuntu or Ubuntu-based distro". I'm happy about any advice, info, opinion etc. I can get :)

Comment: Very new system will need latest distribution to have latest kernel & drivers. You may even need to add ppa to get even newer kernel & drivers to support very new hardware. Do you have just Xe or also nVidia? Similar issues for any distribution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/643216/dual-boot-install-failure-of-debian-11-win-10-on-uefi-only-dell-inspiron-17-770  & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204648/install-ubuntu-on-dell-inspiron-14-7490

Comment: Well, I only know what the OP said. Generally, it is best to clearly say what you mean, and not muddy the waters.

Comment: @oldfred The laptop comes with a GeForce MX350. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Best to boot in Safe Mode & install optional drivers to get nVidia driver installed. Otherwise you have to use nomodeset boot parameter to boot live installer and first boot.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP: Generally, on Ask Ubuntu [and other SE sites], it is better to limit yourself to asking one thing per question. It is better to post multiple separate questions than to bundle them up all into one.

1. Ubuntu [and a lot of other distros, too], use EXT4 by default, not NTFS. Windows and Linux can both read NTFS partitions, you might need to install a package into Ubuntu to let it write to NTFS partitions, but it shouldn't be hard. Instead, I suggest installing Windows as normal, using some portion of the disk. Install Ubuntu as normal, as a dual boot. The, create one more partition using a live CD (use `gparted`) that you store your files on. Make it NTFS.
2. Yes.
3. The official system requirements from Windows say this

   > Hard disk space: 16 GB for 32-bit OS or 20 GB for 64-bit OS

   That is almost no storage and isn't helpful. If you just want, say, Microsoft Office and a web browser, 64 GB should be enough. But if you want large games, like Microsoft Flight Simulator, then you would need more space. Without knowing what you plan to install, I can't give much advice.
4. I don't know. Probobly depends on which distro you choose, but try Googling for "Dell Inspiron 14 Model 7400 fingerprint sensor Ubuntu" and see what comes up
5. Yes. On OEM laptops, product keys are tied to the hardware, so even if you installed Ubuntu with no Windows, and then later installed Windows over it, then you would still keep the product key.

Comment: Thanks, that already helps me a lot! I think I will try to install only a Linux distro, replacing Windows. I was thinking about dual-boot because I wasn't sure whether I'd be able to return to Windows. I don't really "need" Windows on the new laptop as I already have a Windows PC as my main computer.

Comment: Make a Windows install disk/USB with Windows first.  It is easier than using Linux/Ubuntu to make an install disk, can be done but needs proper programs(woeUSB, mkUSB).